# Access 2000 Calling Append Query through GUI

Tags: ms-access

I am calling a append query in access 2000 through macro GUI. Every time I call/run the macro it will pop 2 message boxes saying "you are about to append a table" and one more message box saying "yor are about to append X number of records to table a". I have tried avoiding these messages by going to Tools->options and unchecked Confirm Action queries. Is this is the right query or is there any other way, please provide me some examples.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can any once give me some examples or suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't recall Accesss 2000 macros, but you want to find an initial statement to turn warnings off. You may have to do this is the vba that triggers the macro (If you are doing it in VBA.).

```
docmd.SetWarnings False
```

Comment: @Jeff....Thanks for your reply ....Am using the macros in the GUI....as you can see in the image above, i have used the Set Warnings property to NO